# How to limit an SQL result set to not too common items

Tags: sql, subquery, union, limit

Problem: I have a list of names and addresses. Some names (persons) have the same address (street, zip code, town) like others. I want to select all those names with addresses with no more than three occurrences and from the rest the first three names each of a bunch pointing to the same address.
Example:

```
Albert | Adr1
Berta  | Adr1
Cesar  | Adr1
Donald | Adr1
Eric   | Adr2
Fritz  | Adr2
Gerd   | Adr2
Henry  | Adr3
```

The result set should be

```
Albert | Adr1 
Berta  | Adr1
Cesar  | Adr1
Eric   | Adr2
Fritz  | Adr2
Gerd   | Adr2
Henry  | Adr3
```

Donald is missing because he is the 4th of a group with the same address.
Can this result be achieved with UNIONs and subqueries? Something like

```
select * from addresses where address in 
(select address from addresses group by address having count(address) <= 3)
UNION
select * from addresses where address in 
(select address from addresses group by address having count(address) > 3 limit 3)
```

I know that this query is wrong because it limits the complete result set of addresses with more than 3 occurences.
I wonder if this can be done in a single SELECT with UNIONs and subqueries. I will do it now procedurally with PHP/MySQL, but just for fun would be interested in an SQL only solution.

I had a look at [SQL query with limit on rows from one table, not the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084893), but this does not reflect my situation - or does it?

Comment: how can you recognize that Donald is the forth member of the group ? how this data is sorted?

Comment: The sort order does not matter. It has to be any 3 addresses out of more than 3.
The server is MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  PersonName,
        Address
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM addresses WHERE Address = a.Address AND PersonName < a.PersonName) CountLess
            FROM    addresses a
        ) sub
WHERE   sub.CountLess <= 2
```

Comment: Very ingenious. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
select name, address
from
 ( select *, row_number() over (partition by address order by name) as namenum
   from yourTable
 ) t
where namenum <= 3;
```

Comment: This works in SQL Server, and Oracle and DB2 both support the OVER clause as well. I don't think mysql has caught up with this part of the standard yet, just like how SQL Server doesn't require semi-colons yet.

Comment: This is not supported by MySQL. The solution pointed me to http://explainextended.com/2009/09/14/mysql-emulating-row_number-with-multiple-order-by-conditions/, though, where a similar problem is treated and the functionality of Robs solution is emulated.