# MYSQL - select first 4 records for each category in a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table `INVENTORY` that has among other columns `CATEGORY` and `UPDATED`.
Sorting the table by these columns is easy:

`SELECT * FROM INVENTORY ORDER BY CATEGORY ASC, UPDATED ASC`

What I want is to get a result set that contains only the first 4 rows from each category.
Any idea how to get it done?

Comment: is this possible in one query ?

Answer (score 2):

Very much the same as [How to limit an SQL result set to not too common items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153410/how-to-limit-an-sql-result-set-to-not-too-common-items/2153595#2153595)

You could try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    (   SELECT  COUNT(1) 
                        FROM    INVENTORY 
                        WHERE   CATEGORY = i.CATEGORY 
                        AND     UPDATED < i.UPDATED
                    ) CountTotal
            FROM    @INVENTORY i
        ) sub
WHERE   sub.CountTotal <= 3
```

Comment: This is wrong. It returns only entries from categories that have less than 4 entries, not with 3 entries at most.