# Select 2 products from each category in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Pretty similar to [MYSQL - select first 4 records for each category in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154087/mysql-select-first-4-records-for-each-category-in-a-table) but there isn't an accepted answer and the one answer there doesn't make much sense so i'm asking again.

I have a `PRODUCTS` table with 3 columns: `ID`, `NAME` and `CATEGORY`
What i would like to know now is if it's at all possible to select 2 products for each distinct category without doing queries in a PHP loop.

The order of the selected products is of no importance, they might as well be random. But it's important that i only have max 2 products per category.

So a good result set would be

```
ID  ; NAME   ; CATEGORY
:::::::::::::::::::::::
152 ; APPLE  ; FRUIT
185 ; ORANGE ; FRUIT
145 ; BEEF   ; MEAT
141 ; PORK   ; MEAT
410 ; PEPSI  ; DRINKS
585 ; CARROT ; VEGETABLES
585 ; TOMATO ; VEGETABLES
```

Comment: how your result supposed to be ? put it in your code to better understanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines will work:

```
SELECT id, name, category 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         IF( @prev <> category, 
             @rownum := 1, 
             @rownum := @rownum+1 
         ) AS rank, 
         @prev := category, 
         @rownum  
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM products 
    ORDER BY category, rand()
  ) random_prodcts
) products_ranked 
WHERE rank <= 2;
```

It orders them randomly within the categories, then pulls them out tracking how many it's got from each.

Not sure how nicely it will scale though.

EDIT: Tried it with a few thousand records and it seems ok.

Comment: This works beautifully. Just make sure you SET the vars before running the query. Otherwise it will not work. SET @prev=0,@rownum=0;

Comment: MariaDB is working, but MySQL not working

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are looking for.

```
SET @I=0; 
SET @C='';
SELECT ID, Name, Category FROM (
    SELECT B.*, 
    IF(@C != B.Category, @I:=1, @I:=@I+1) AS RowNum,
    @C:=B.Category
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, Name, Category FROM Products GROUP BY Name, Category ORDER BY Category
    ) AS B HAVING RowNum <= 2
) AS A
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but i can't seem to get my head around the RowNum var ... when I select it along with the ID, Name and Category columns it sometimes also contains 3 while the HAVING clause states that it should be no higher than 2?

Comment: That's really weird - I just tried this, and noticed that it works with <= 2 and gives rownums 1 and 3, but the correct 2 records, but if you do it with <= 3, it doesn't work any more - it gives only 2 records per category and still rownums 1 and 3. Try it with a selection of values - I can't figure out the relationship.

Have you tried my solution at all?

Comment: @Simon143: Yes, your solution actually gives me the correct rowNumbers ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FULL SQL:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.category
FROM the_table AS t
, (SELECT MIN(id) AS id_min FROM the_table GROUP BY category) AS t1
, (SELECT MAX(id) AS id_max FROM the_table GROUP BY category) AS t2
WHERE (t.id=t1.id_min) OR  (t.id=t2.id_max)
```

The query picks the min and the max of each category and return both of them (or only one if it is the same).

You said "The order of the selected products is of no importance, they might as well be random", so this method should be ok.