# Select at least one from each category?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, random

[SQLFiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/edd1b/1/0)

I've got an SQLite database with a bunch of test/exam questions. Each **question** belongs to one **question category**.

My table looks like this:
[image: so_questions table]

**The goal**
What I'm trying to do is select 5 random questions, but the result must contain **at least** one from each category. The goal is to select a random set of questions with questions from each category.

For example, the output could be question IDs `1, 2, 5, 7, 8`, or `2, 3, 6, 7, 8` or `8, 6, 3, 1, 7`.

**ORDER BY category_id, RANDOM()**
I can get a random list of questions from SQLite by executing the SQL below, but how would I make sure that the result contains a question from each of my categories?

[image: SELECT ORDER BY category_id, random]

Basically, I'm looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633619/select-2-products-from-each-category-in-mysql), the SQLite version.

I would like to get only 5 results, but one(or more) from each category, with all the categories represented in the result set.

**Bounty**
Added a bounty because I'm curious whether or not it is possible to accomplish this in SQLite only. I can do it in SQLite+Java, but is there a way to do this in SQLite only? :)

[SQLFiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/edd1b/1/0)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(category_id) FROM questions LIMIT 0,5
Have you tried this ?

Comment: That'd work to get a unique list of categories, but what I want is not that easy :(.

Comment: off topic: yeey, found a co-workers question thanks to our stackoverflow widget!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to the answer is that there are two kinds of questions in the result: for each category, one question that must be *constrained* to come from that category; and some remaining questions.

First, the constrained questions: we just select one record from each category:

```sql
SELECT id, category_id, question_text, 1 AS constrained, max(random()) AS r
FROM so_questions
GROUP BY category_id
```

(This query relies on a feature introduced in SQLite 3.7.11 (in Jelly Bean or later): in a query `SELECT a, max(b)`, the value of `a` is guaranteed to come from the record that has the maximum `b` value.)

We also have to get the non-constrained questions (filtering out the duplicates that are already in the constrained set will happen in the next step):

```sql
SELECT id, category_id, question_text, 0 AS constrained, random() AS r
FROM so_questions
```

When we combine these two queries with `UNION` and then group by the `id`, we have all the duplicates together. Selecting `max(constrained)` then ensures that for the groups that have duplicates, only the constrained question remains (while all the other questions have only one record per group anyway).

Finally, the `ORDER BY` clause ensures that the constrained questions come first, followed by some random other questions:

```sql
SELECT *, max(constrained)
FROM (SELECT id, category_id, question_text, 1 AS constrained, max(random()) AS r
      FROM so_questions
      GROUP BY category_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, category_id, question_text, 0 AS constrained, random() AS r
      FROM so_questions)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY constrained DESC, r
LIMIT 5
```

---

For earlier SQLite/Android versions, I haven't found a solution without using a temporary table (because the subquery for the constrained question must be used multiple times, but does not stay constant because of the `random()`):

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE constrained AS
SELECT (SELECT id
        FROM so_questions
        WHERE category_id = cats.category_id
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 1) AS id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category_id
      FROM so_questions) AS cats;

SELECT ids.id, category_id, question_text
FROM (SELECT id
      FROM (SELECT id, 1 AS c
            FROM constrained
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, 0 AS c
            FROM so_questions
            WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM constrained))
      ORDER BY c DESC, random()
      LIMIT 5) AS ids
JOIN so_questions ON ids.id = so_questions.id;

DROP TABLE constrained;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Thanks for the explanation. I've done about the same in SQLite+Java, but this is indeed a 'pure SQLite' solution as requested :).  (may award bounty in 1 hr)

Comment: (I do realise that Jelly Bean is on only 1.8% of the Android devices out there. What I was curious about was a pure SQLite solution, not a pure SQLite solution that'll work on all Android devices. So for me, this answer is pretty good.)

Answer (score 4):

Basically what you are looking for is **select top N max values**.  I spend 3-4 hours in the morning for searching it. ( still i haven't success in it, you may need to wait few more hours ).

For the temporary solution you can use **group by** option as follows,

String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM so_questions group by category_id;";

the output is as follows,

[image]

will be back with exact your requirement.

Comment: But then I'd still have the problem of getting one from each category when selecting only 5 questions. It just selects the first 5 rows from the result set.
(In this case, the rows with id 1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: @TerrySeidler, nopes, output will be 4 rows only because there are only 1,2,3,4 distinct category

Comment: But the OP wants 5 rows at random, which must contain at least one row from each category...

Comment: @Sam, that means any one category will get repeat as there are total 4 categories only, right ?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't matter which category repeats.

Comment: Yep. That's why it says "at least one from each category", not "max one" ;)
When I execute your query, I get: http://files.salteh.net/temp/so_table.jpg

I would like only 5 results, but one from each category :)

Comment: really you got that output ? try, `unique` instead of `distinct` please.

Comment: My SQLite Manager seems to be of the opinion that `unique` doesn't exist(?).

Comment: @TerrySeidler, i will be back with another idea/option tomorrow, its my sleeping now, see ya :)

Comment: @TerrySeidler, i have updated my answer, please check it, however it returns 4 rows as result, i know this part, i will be back.

Comment: well output looks like, but i am not satisfied, as i said what you are looking for is **[select top N max values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql?sort=votes&pagesize=50)**

Comment: @TerrySeidler, sorry, still didn't find the correct answer, how you are going ?

Comment: Hey! No problem! I have currently solved the problem using both SQLite and Java, but may start a bounty at some point just to satisfy my curiosity :).

Comment: wooo.. ok then i will prepare my answer for it. do let me know when you start Bounty :P

Answer (score 2):

Since it's sqlite (thus local): How slow would it be to just query until you have 5 answers and four different categories, dropping the duplicate category rows each iteration.

I think, if each category is equally represented, that it would be highly unlikely that you need more than 3 iterations which should still be below a second.

It's not algorithmically nice, but to me using random() in a SQL statement isn't algorithmically nice anyway.

Comment: Nice observation! This does seem to be the best method to get what I want. When I came up with this problem yesterday I was still hoping for an SQL-only solution, but this is a valid alternative.  I'll have a look at implementing this tonight :).