# Select at least one from each category but no more than one, and no duplicates of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table such as the following:

```
 Id | Vehicle Type | Manufacturer
 --------------------------------
 1  | Car          | SpaceCo
 2  | Car          | NeatCarsInc
 3  | Car          | NeatCarsInc
 4  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo
 5  | Spaceship    | NeatCarsInc
 6  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo
 7  | Boat         | WeMakeBoats
 8  | Boat         | SpaceCo
 9  | Boat         | NeatCarsInc
```

I need to be able to write a query to meet the following:

- **Req #1** Ensure that a given Vehicle Type is not repeated in the result set
- **Req #2** Ensure that a given Manufacturer is not repeated in the result set
- **Req #3** If there are any entries for a Vehicle Type then there should be an output row for each Vehicle Type (within the constraints of Req #1 and Req #2)
- *NB: Each Manufacturer can appear 0-1 times in the result set, and there is no requirement to try to select every Manufacturer*

I am not particular about which Id is returned (e.g. the Minimum Id would be sufficient).

A valid result set could be:

```
1  | Car          | SpaceCo
5  | Spaceship    | NeatCarsInc      
7  | Boat         | WeMakeBoats
```

This would be equally acceptable:

```
2  | Car          | NeatCarsInc
4  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo      
7  | Boat         | WeMakeBoats
```

However, this would ideally **not** be acceptable (as it left out a row for the Car Vehicle Type, thereby violating Req #3):

```
9  | Boat         | NeatCarsInc
6  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo
```

What's important is that **neither** the Vehicle Type or Manufacturer columns have any repeats, and that, if possible, an entry is selected for each Vehicle Type.

Note that this is similar but different from this question: [Select at least one from each category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516485/select-at-least-one-from-each-category) as we are (1) working with two categories, and (2) cannot permit duplicate entries for either category.

---

**Attempted Approach**

Reflecting, I'm not sure that this is possible in SQL as it sounds dangerously close to the Knapsack problem...

The closest I can get is to:

1. Rank over Vehicle Type, pick the first entry for each Vehicle Type
2. Rank this set over Manufacturer, pick the first entry for each Manufacturer

This requires me to violate **Req #3**, i.e. it could produce any of the following results depending on the rank order used:

Ordering by Ascending Id:

```
1  | Car          | SpaceCo
7  | Boat         | WeMakeBoats
```

Ordering by Descending Id:

```
6  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo
9  | Boat         | NeatCarsInc
```

Ordering by Random Id (Possibility):

```
2  | Car          | NeatCarsInc
6  | Spaceship    | SpaceCo
7  | Boat         | WeMakeBoats
```

Sample SQL for this as follows:

```
   SELECT Id, VehicleType, Manufacturer
   FROM
   (
     SELECT 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Manufacturer ORDER BY [Id] ASC) ManufacturerRank,
       Id,
       VehicleType,
       Manufacturer
     FROM
     (
       SELECT 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleType ORDER BY [Id] ASC) VehicleRank,
         Id,
         VehicleType,
         Manufacturer
       FROM
         Vehicles
     ) RankedPerVehicleType
     WHERE VehicleRank = 1
   ) RankedPerManufacturer
   WHERE ManufacturerRank = 1
```

Comment: Each set depends on the other. I don't think it can be done in *just* SQL. I think you need to do it in procedural way.

Comment: what about this approach
1.select all distinct Vehicle Type first --say table 1
2.select all distinct Manufacturer -say table 2
2. in Procedure or function, iterate through each row for table 1
3. for the first row select any random from table2
4. for the other rows select any random but not which was used in previous row

Comment: @MattMitchel Why would you even store data like this?? I mean `Id` `2` and `3` have the same data.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran - Assume they are individual vehicles, and there's another (irrelevant) RegistrationPlateNumber field for Id 2 and Id 3.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - I think you're right

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper - The approach sounds like a potential option, but would require temporary tables and cursors I think, i.e. a procedural approach as GurwinderSingh suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bother about ID, this could you give a way

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (Id INT, Vehicle_Type VARCHAR(250), Manufacturer VARCHAR(250))

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,'Car','SpaceCo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Car','NeatCarsInc'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Car','NeatCarsInc'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Spaceship','SpaceCo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Spaceship','NeatCarsInc'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'Spaceship','SpaceCo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Boat','WeMakeBoats'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'Boat','SpaceCo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'Boat','NeatCarsInc'


SELECT  Vehicle_Type,Manufacturer  
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Vehicle_Type) AS SNO, Vehicle_Type FROM #TAB 
)VT 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Manufacturer) AS SNO,  Manufacturer FROM #TAB 
)MF
ON VT.SNO= MF.SNO
```

And the result will be

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Vehicle_Type | Manufacturer |
+--------------+--------------+
| Boat         | NeatCarsInc  |
| Car          | SpaceCo      |
| Spaceship    | WeMakeBoats  |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: add a new row: *10,plane ,NeatCarsInc* and try again. It'll fail

Comment: Dear @GurwinderSingh OP mentioned that `Each Manufacturer can appear 0-1 times in the result set, and there is no requirement to try to select every Manufacturer.` Please read Question

Comment: @ShakeerMirza - This won't work with different data. For one example, make all 3 car entries from NeatCarsInc and your code would still return SpaceCo as the car manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Id, VehicleType, Manufacturer
   FROM
   (
     SELECT 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Manufacturer ORDER BY [Id] ASC) ManufacturerRank,
       Id,
       VehicleType,
       Manufacturer
     FROM
     (
       SELECT 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleType ORDER BY [Id] ASC) VehicleRank,
         Id,
         VehicleType,
         Manufacturer
       FROM
         Vehicles
     ) RankedPerVehicleType
     WHERE VehicleRank = 1
   ) RankedPerManufacturer
   WHERE ManufacturerRank = 1
```

Comment: Move distinct to after Select. Other wise it will give Syntax error\

Comment: I'm not sure this adds anything? It's the sample approach I shared with a Distinct added, which doesn't address any of the challenges of the sample approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to care about the id, this would do the trick:

```
select distinct [Vehicle Type] into #1 from table_1
select distinct [Manufacturer] into #2 from table_1
select * from #1 cross join #2 
drop table #1
drop table #2
```