# one product in many categories, finding n number of products from each category - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have products belonging to multiple categories.

```
products         categories       products_categories
------------     -------------    --------------------
product_id       category_id      product_id
product_title    category_title   category_id
```

I want to get n number, could be lets say 6, of last inserted different products from each category. I would also make a join of products on it to fetch the product info, however that should be easy.

what i mean from different products is that if one product belongs to many categories, it should come only once in one category and other category should get another n, 6 products, if available else whatever available.

I could try something like defined here using the rank [Select 2 products from each category in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633619/select-2-products-from-each-category-in-mysql?rq=1)
but this solution does not handle the condition when product belongs to multiple categories, and i want different n number of products in each category.

here is some sample data

```
pid catid    insertion_date
284 48  2/4/2013 1:14:16 AM
278 41  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
278 43  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
284 45  2/4/2013 12:55:24 PM
284 44  2/4/2013 12:55:24 PM
285 41  2/4/2013 1:28:37 AM
278 42  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
285 47  2/4/2013 1:28:42 AM
285 48  2/4/2013 12:50:44 PM
278 46  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
278 47  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
278 48  2/4/2013 1:25:03 PM
286 43  2/7/2013 3:20:40 PM
286 44  2/7/2013 3:20:40 PM
243 41  2/14/2013 3:30:59 PM
243 42  2/14/2013 3:30:59 PM
243 43  2/14/2013 3:30:59 PM
266 41  2/14/2013 3:51:40 PM
266 47  2/14/2013 3:51:40 PM
266 48  2/14/2013 3:51:40 PM
286 41  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
286 42  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
286 45  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
286 46  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
286 47  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
286 48  2/14/2013 3:51:55 PM
254 41  2/14/2013 3:52:07 PM
254 43  2/14/2013 3:52:07 PM
254 45  2/14/2013 3:52:07 PM
254 47  2/14/2013 3:52:07 PM
254 48  2/14/2013 3:52:07 PM
252 41  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
252 42  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
252 45  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
252 46  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
252 47  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
252 48  2/14/2013 3:52:23 PM
169 46  2/14/2013 3:55:54 PM
221 46  2/14/2013 3:56:08 PM
```

if somebody has a better solution to do such things in php, please suggest.

Comment: give us sample data with desired result so we can work it out.

Comment: added the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This example will give you 2 latest `product_title` based on latest `product_ID` for every `category_title`.

```
SELECT  a.category_title, c.product_title
FROM    categories a
        INNER JOIN products_categories b
            ON a.category_ID = b.category_ID
        INNER JOIN products c
            ON b.product_ID = c.product_ID
WHERE   
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    products_categories d
            WHERE   b.category_ID = d.category_ID AND
                    c.product_ID <= d.product_ID
        ) <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17c3c/2)

Comment: i think it is not good, none of your product is into the mutiple categories, however I will re-check it out in a while and update you. will it be good to fetch such query from thousands records?

Comment: yes, it is not good enough, it fails if u have products into multiple categories and that is my basic requirement. i think we need a solution using rank but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a repeated value to be taken only once, refer to [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html), which will return you a result with unique values for given column.

And to get the last inserted ones, [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html), using `DESC`

To limit how many rows you want, [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html)

So your final query is:
`SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM products_categories ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 6`

**Edit:** Trying the *actual way* you meant it, so far can't get a proper result, yet I believe this will be doable with `JOIN`, however I can't just form it at the moment. I'll have a look at this again later on, until then good luck in finding, I'm also quite curious about this kind of output, so will be adding this to *favorites*.

Comment: this will give you 6 results only, not 6 results per category.

Comment: trust me, it is not that easy. your query will give distinct 6 records from all categories. I want n, 6, products from each category and that too only the last 6 inserted ones.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood then, let me try `that one`.

Answer (score 0):

My SQL is a bit rusty, but I guess you can use the NOT IN () to remove any duplicates. If you have a statement to get your first 6 products, then use something like:

```
WITH Statement1 as (SELECT .... FROM ....)  -- Get your first 6 products
WITH Statement2 as (SELECT ... FROM .... NOT IN (Statement1)) -- Get 6 new one, NOT in Statement1
... and so on ...
```

Not the prettiest code, but you should understand the concept of what I'm trying to say.

To get all in result then you can create a view to easily get them:

```
CREATE VIEW AllProducts AS
  Statement1 UNION Statement2 UNION ...;

SELECT .... FROM AllProducts;
```

Comment: it is difficult to make a single query out of your suggestion. what you saying is actually the description of the my problem not the solution. I can not fire multiple queries.

Comment: Using the WITH (as I updated to) you should be able to join all statements in the end if you only want one list with all results.

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. Using the UNION you should be able to combine all statements. Edited my post.

Comment: I understood what you saying, but it cant be done this way. here, we need to make inner query for each statement, also making statement 1 as a inner query for statement 2 seems not doable in union and mysql. even if we somehow do it, it is very expensive in nature.