# Select 2 random rows from a table from each category MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table which is called **`Questions.`**

Rows in this table have one of their fields called **`category_name`** and I currently have *5 different category names*

My question is:

**How can I select 2 random rows from each category, and return them as an array?**

Obviously I need 10 questions returned back but the way I have it now it might select unequal number of questions between the categories.

Here is my function this far which selects all questions at the moment:

```
  function populateQuestions(){

        global $dbc;
         $query = "SELECT * FROM Questions";

         $result = $dbc->getAll($query);
         shuffle($result);

         return $result;  
    }
```

My **`category_names`** are:

- Meat
- Vegetables
- Fish
- Exotic
- Local

*My tables are quite small and the game is not really speed-oriented so I prefer keeping all the questions in one table as they are now.*

Comment: Use the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140589/mysql-query-select-top-3-rows-from-table-for-each-category?rq=1 and use `ORDER BY cagtegory_name, RAND()`

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633619/select-2-products-from-each-category-in-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633619/select-2-products-from-each-category-in-mysql)