# Select the first 3 rows of each table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a database with 69 tables and I want to select only the first three records of each table.

I can do it *per table* with:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * 
  FROM table_schema.table_name
```

However if I was to do this manually, it would take a lot of time.

Could you please suggest a workaround?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154087/mysql-select-first-4-records-for-each-category-in-a-table) but I can get it to work (I don't know how to modify it for MSSQL)

**EDIT** Thanks for your replies. I probably wasn't clear enough: I meant I wanted to parse each individual table and only get the top 3 records than move on to the next one. 
Yaroslav's code below is what I needed

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
  FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: First three records according to what column?, a table doesn't have a *natural order* or something like that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you have:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
  FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: You are welcome, the @Aushin solution is fast and clean too, only "but" is that MSforeachtable and MSforeachdb are undocumented stored procedures, therefore Microsoft does not support them and can change them any time

Comment: Just a follow up question: what would be the best way to export all of the results at once? It seems like I can only export "per table"? Thanks

Comment: Creating a new question will help to get the best results...but right now what occurs to me is to use PRINT somewhere...just guessing

Comment: Is there a way to order the tables in abc order (like the appear when you click the Database --> Tables?)

Comment: add an `ORDER BY name` after the FROM clause

Comment: I added the name as in:

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 '''+ name + ''', * FROM 

'+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'

  FROM sys.tables

EXEC(@sql)

Answer (score 8):

```
 exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 3 * from ?'
```

Comment: Thanks but that only works if you want to do it per table manually. Yaroslav's comment below address what I needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Phil - What do you mean with "only works if you want to do it per table manually"?, that's what you were asking, right?

Comment: Also, be sure to click the check mark next to Yaroslav's answer :)

Comment: Just did. Your solution also works. Thank you both. Have an awesome day :)