# Get first row in table while printing out Table name and Column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a quick overlook of the data in a MS SQL datase and found the following code which gives me all but the last column I need. This third column should show data from the first row.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

[image]

So my question is how I should formulate the SQL query to get a third column with data from the first row)?

//**Update**
This code gives me all I want except what table the data comes from. (In a similar question answered by Yaroslav at [Select the first 3 rows of each table in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741212/select-the-first-3-rows-of-each-table-in-a-database))

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)=''; 
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
FROM sys.tables
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: How can you have the same number of columns if selecting metadata for different tables?

Comment: are you trying to find the datatype of the column or the actual value from the table ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure I undertand your question? Maybe my formulation of columns is unclear? In the picture I consider it to show 2 columns. To the right of COLUMN_NAME I would like it to say something generic and then for each row it should present the data in that column. The purpose of this is for me to find out what kind of data there is in each table without going through each table ni SSMS manually.

Comment: @Markov It's the actual value I'm after. I ellaborated a little more in my comment to Tim.

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson I get it now.  I think you would need to use dynamic SQL in order to do this.  You could use a scalar subquery for the third column, piping in the column and table name you want to retrieve.

Comment: Totaly agree with @TimBiegeleisen that you need dynamic sql,
its seem like the step that you need to take here is:
Select all the table and columns with row_number into #table
Then used while loop with dynamic sql that would hardcode the first two column for you(Table_Name|Column_Name|) and then would do select top 1 and you have to plug in the column names, the row number would help in that case, probably need another loop (or  use for xml) for the columns. Something like that would build you a string then exec one by one and insert the value into a another table or exec all with unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, if I get this correctly, was an undocumented stored procedure `sp_MsForeachTable`. The questionmark is a placeholder for the table's name there:

Hint: edit "YourDataBase"...

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'USE YourDataBase;SELECT TOP 1 ''?'' AS TableName, * FROM ?';
```

With this query you can explore all first rows easily

```
CREATE TABLE #test(TableName NVARCHAR(MAX),Content XML)

EXEC sp_msforeachtable 
'USE YourDataBase;INSERT INTO #test SELECT ''?'' AS TableName, (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ? FOR XML PATH(''row''))';

SELECT * FROM #test;
```

### UPDATE

Your own code would return the table's name also. Try this

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)=''; 
SELECT @sql=@sql+'SELECT TOP 3 ''' + t.[name] + ''' AS TableName, * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
FROM sys.tables t
EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isnt much but it build you a select statement, you can then loop through each statement exec each statement or write a union, But I guess it could be a good starting point

**Edit:** You could also write a loop and exec each statement in a loop insert the value into a final table, Then just select from that table and you should be good.

```
SELECT
    t.String
   ,t.q
   ,t.TABLE_NAME
   ,t.q2
   ,t.tbname
   ,t.com2
   ,t.q4
   ,t.COLUMN_NAME
   ,t.q5
   ,t.Columnname
   ,t.com3
   ,t.ColName
   ,t.[From]
   ,t.FromSelect
FROM (SELECT
        'Select top 1 ' AS String
       ,'''' q
       ,TABLE_NAME
       ,'''' q2
       ,'as TableName'
        as tbname
       ,',' com2

       ,'''' q4
       ,COLUMN_NAME
       ,'''' q5
       ,'as COLUMN_NAME'
       as Columnname
       ,',' com3
       ,COLUMN_NAME as ColName
       , 'Value From ' as [From]
       ,TABLE_NAME as FromSelect
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC, COLUMN_NAME) rn
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The result will be something like this for each table.

```
Select top 1    '   zipcodes    '   as TableName    ,   '   CITY    '   as COLUMN_NAME  ,   CITY    Value From  zipcodes
Select top 1    '   _BHCAMERAPRICE  '   as TableName    ,   '   _BHID   '   as COLUMN_NAME  ,   _BHID   Value From  _BHCAMERAPRICE
```

Comment: Looks awesome, I will try this out tomorrow at the office. Get back to you!

Comment: I like the structure provided but (and bare with me here I never write SQL code) I don't see how I will get the values from the tables? Updated my question with code providing me with everything I need but the Table name.