# append output of multiple sql statements into one file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a database of 500 tables.

Following [Select the first 3 rows of each table in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741212/select-the-first-3-rows-of-each-table-in-a-database), i can get the top 3 rows of every table, but the output is 500 tables.

Is it possible to write these results to a single csv/tab or | delimited text document.

I would like

```
col1 col2 col3
...  ...  ...
...  ...  ...
...  ...  ...
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
...  ...  ...  ...  ...
```

in the final file.

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: How are you at programming? You probably need to do this in an external tool, or using some much more complex dynamic sql that your previous question.

Comment: @TomC my SQL programming is basic, but can do so in R/python

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I amended my question

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things with this solution.

1. xp_cmdshell is used, and that can be bad. It also needs to be configured to be used, so probably not the best way to get the csv.
2. This creates the csv inside a temp table, and that is what is exported.
3. Some columns does not convert to varchar (like varbinary, image etc)

Think it will help. I've tested it on my database, and I got everything out.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Temp
CREATE TABLE ##Temp
(
Col varchar(max)
)
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
Select @sql=@sql+'INSERT ##Temp SELECT TOP 3 ' + colnames + ' FROM [' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '].['+name+']'+';'
from
(
select  a.object_id, a.name, a.schema_id, STUFF((SELECT '+'',''+Convert(varchar(max), ' + QUOTENAME(a.name)  + ')'
FROM 
(Select * from sys.columns c where object_id = a.object_id) a
ORDER BY a.column_id   
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE    
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')    
        ,1,5,'')  colnames
FROM sys.tables a
) a

exec (@sql)
delete #Temp where Col is null
declare @TempFileName varchar(255) = 'C:\Temp\Youfile.csv'
Select @Command = 'bcp "Select * from ##Temp" queryout "' + @TempFileName + '" -S' + @@ServerName + ' -T -c -q'
exec xp_cmdshell @Command, NO_OUTPUT
```