# mySql limiting joined table rows but include all which matches join condition if limit is not reached

Tags: mysql, join

This is similar to this question:

[SQL query with limit on rows from one table, not the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084893/sql-query-with-limit-on-rows-from-one-table-not-the-result-set)

but the problem with give answer is:

```
SELECT t3.a, t2.b FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 LIMIT 5) t3
LEFT JOIN t2 ON ...
```

when select from t1, it takes random (I am not sure if really random) rows. We can add ordering. But when it orders, it also takes last or first rows. So it might take first 5 rows which do not match join condition anyway.

What I want is to take rows which match the filter and matches join condition. And then limit them. Why I want to limit is because I do not want to load my database too much if user uses filter which takes it run too much.

Currently limiting is just by dates using condition between. And before running SQL query, date interval is checked if it is not too wide.

But the problem with date interval limit is that it gives very little result set if other filters are set.

Comment: can you give a more complete example ? your explanation is a bit abstract, so not completly sure what you mean to do, because it sounds like you dont need subqueries at all, just the right joins and the right conditions on the join

Comment: @DarkMukke - solved after writing the question. I am not wanting to post the real sql which is used in sofware, but then I would need to remake it. Is that still needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finishing this post, not submitted yet, got the idea how to solve, and it worked. So since I wrote  so much, I am am posting the solution.

Move joins in subquery, something like this (had not tested this, because was testing my real application sql)

```
SELECT t3.a, t3.b FROM (
   SELECT * FROM t1 
      INNER JOIN t2 ON ...
         LIMIT 5
    ) t3
```

I use inner join, because that what I was doing in real application. So now we have limit of 5 rows which matches t1 and t2, not random of t1 (or first or last if ordering)